# Pandas - remove numbers from start of string in series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I've got a series of addresses and would like a series with just the street name. The only catch is some of the addresses don't have a house number, and some do.

So if I have a series that looks like:

```
Idx
 0      11000 SOUTH PARK
 1      20314 BRAKER LANE
 2      203 3RD ST
 3      BIRMINGHAM PARK
 4      E 12TH
```

What function would I write to get

```
Idx
 0      SOUTH PARK
 1      BRAKER LANE
 2      3RD ST
 3      BIRMINGHAM PARK
 4      E 12TH
```

where any 'words' made entirely of numeric characters at the beginning of the string have been removed? As you can see above, I would like to retain the 3 that '3RD STREET' starts with. I'm thinking a regular expression but this is beyond me. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `str.replace` with regex *^\d+\s+* to remove leading digits:

```
s.str.replace('^\d+\s+', '')

Out[491]:
0         SOUTH PARK
1        BRAKER LANE
2             3RD ST
3    BIRMINGHAM PARK
4             E 12TH
Name: Idx, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.replace('\d+\s', '')` is what I came up with:

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({'IDx': ['11000 SOUTH PARK',
                        '20314 BRAKER LANE',
                        '203 3RD ST',
                        'BIRMINGHAM PARK',
                        'E 12TH']})

df
Out[126]: 
                 IDx
0   11000 SOUTH PARK
1  20314 BRAKER LANE
2         203 3RD ST
3    BIRMINGHAM PARK
4             E 12TH

df.IDx = df.IDx.str.replace('\d+\s', '')   

df
Out[128]: 
               IDx
0       SOUTH PARK
1      BRAKER LANE
2           3RD ST
3  BIRMINGHAM PARK
4           E 12TH
```